# Magento Backend > Product Attributes showing less attributes that it should

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

When in backend I can't see all custom attributes. Same occurs in frontend.

I selected EAV_ATTRIBUTE table and can see 179 product attributes (type = 4).
But backend Product > Attributes shows only 119.

Anyone know what could be happening?

Magento Version: 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN the admin grid for attributes, the attribute collection is retrieved like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')
        ->addVisibleFilter();
```

So not all the attributes that exist are listed in there. Only the ones marked as `is_visible` in the `catalog_eav_attribute` table.

Try this select and see what you get.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    eav_attribute e
    LEFT JOIN `catalog_eav_attribute` ce
        ON e.attribute_id = ce.attribute_id
WHERE
    e.entity_type_id = 4 AND
    ce.is_visible = 1
```

This should get you the attributes that are listed in the admin grid.

Comment: Thanks Marius,

Setting `ce.is_visible IS NULL` your query shows me that missing attributes don't have relations with `catalog_eav_attribute`.

I dont know why `catalog_eav_attributes` don't exists for that attributes. It probably happens after my SQL migration from 1.3 to 1.7.0.2.

I will try insert the missing relations in `catalog_eav_attribute`.

Comment: Fixed using your query:

`INSERT INTO catalog_eav_attribute
SELECT e.attribute_id,NULL,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,'',0,0,0,0 FROM eav_attribute e LEFT JOIN catalog_eav_attribute ce ON e.attribute_id = ce.attribute_id WHERE e.entity_type_id = 4 AND ce.is_visible IS NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the database has inconsistent data due to use of direct SQL insert statements or such. Its logical that only the consistent data would show up.

I've seen some import scripts which could lead to such inconsistencies floating around on the 'net.

Maybe you got bitten by one?

Comment: Yeah I got bitten by Magento upgrade scripts. I'm using this environment since 2009 (version 1.2).